# How to permanently change directory in octave?

Tags: directory, octave, octave-gui

Even when I am using he addpath command in octave

For eg: addpath('D:\Random Small Projects\Coursera\Machine Learning\Week 2\machine-learning-ex1\ex1')

when i type pwd
it is showing the curent directory as 'C:\user'

I don't know why the add path command is not working?

Answer (score 3):

`addpath` does not change the directory, it just makes the contents of that folder visible to the current working instance of Octave/MATLAB.

Use [`cd`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Current-Working-Directory.html) to change directory.